# React project displaying blank page on GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

I have a project that is displaying a blank page on GitHub Pages. I have added

```
"homepage": "https://jusmccar.github.io/ContactManager",
```

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

to my `package.json` and ran the commands

```
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
npm run deploy
```

Here is the link to my repo:
[ContactManager](https://github.com/jusmccar/ContactManager)

I have another project [FitClub](https://github.com/jusmccar/FitClub) that it works just fine on so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have errors in your console... _"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')
    at x (ContactList.js:9:46)"_

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here in `App.js`

> ```js
> const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(
>   JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
> );
> ```

You're not doing anything to handle the initial case where there is nothing in local storage.

This causes `null` to be passed to the `contacts` prop in `ContactList`. The code there attempts to use `props.contacts.map()` which leads to this error you see in your browser console...

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')
> at x (ContactList.js:9:46)

I would suggest defaulting to an empty array when `getItem()` returns `null`

```js
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) ?? []
);
```

A further suggestion would be to use TypeScript which would warn you about the potential for `localStorage` to return `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

I think it deployed fine, but there is an error in your ContactsList component. Look it the console.
TypeError: e.contacts is null